# In Java, why does a thread have to compete for resources after waking up from .wait()?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, synchronized, producer-consumer

For example in this classic consumer-producer code snippet:

```
synchronized (this) {
  while (queue.isEmpty()) {
    this.wait();
  }
  queue.remove();
  this.notifyAll();
}
```

The `.wait()` consumer thread that is notified by producer will wake up and then compete for resource with other consumer threads that are waiting on `synchronized (this)`. This causes the race condition. But why don't simply let the `.wait()` consumer to hold the resource until it exists the `synchronized` block?

Comment: are you talking about fairness between the `wait()` consumers?

Comment: well, how do you decide who gets the resource if another consumer also wants the resource? I mean, what would be your solution? Who decides on which consumer to prefer in case multiple consumers try to get the resource?

Comment: That's not a race condition. It is not fair, and might cause starvation. You usually need to make the decision to have a fair scheduling or get the last bit of performance. Java chose the later.

Comment: @k5_ ... and gave `ReentrantLock` to support the former.

Comment: @AKSW I mean, just let the `.wait()` thread to hold the lock when it's sleeping. That way there will be only one thread can be executing in the synchronized the block.

Comment: I rephrase the question.

Comment: @SexyNerd if the thread holds the lock while waiting, how could the producer obtain it to fill the queue? That would lead to a deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

This is a naive question.. Thanks to the comments I think I understand the logic behind of the design now:

1. The `.wait()` thread cannot just hold the lock when waiting, because that way producers are not able to write into the queue.
2. When `.wait()` thread wakes up, why can't just guarantee it to get the lock? Because due to reason #1, `.wait()` thread has to give up the resource before start waiting. At the meantime, other consumer threads could reach the `.wait()` stage. Since there are many thread waiting, who should get the resource? Java chose to treats all threads the same let alone the time in wait.

Comment: Java didn't choose to go with fairness. You have no guarantee that the thread who started to wait first will get the lock first.

Comment: @JBNizet Good catch. Misunderstood the meaning of `fairness`.

Comment: Unfortunately the Java approach avoids both fairness and deterministic behavior. There is no assurance in Java that a particular waiting thread will ever access the shared resource. On average this works, but averages of behavior are not assurances of behavior. Given this lack of assurance that a thread will ever access a shared resource it is clear that the Java threading model is broken.